# simplifying Big-O analysis of a solution using a heap

Tags: big-o

The question: An array is k-sorted, if all elements are misplaced by at most k positions (with respect to the true sorted order). Sort a k sorted array in time
O(n log k).

My solution is this: 
1. Create a new array of size n (this is O(1))
2. Create a min heap of size k and fill it with the first k elements of our array (This is O(k)). 
3. One by one remove the min from our min heap and place it in the new array, and add the next element from the remaining elements (this is (n-k)(logk)).

This will lead to O(k + (n-k)(logk)).

My question is does this lead to O(nlogk)? Can we drop the klogk and the k from the simplified big O? Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does. However, your analysis is not entirely correct - third step has a running time of `n * logk` (not `(n-k) * logk`), because you need to remove all input array elements from the heap and put it into destination array (notice that **all** input array elements go through the heap, one by one). Since the input array has `n` elements and each delete operation is `logk`, this gives `n*logk`.

Apart from definition of big-o, the only inequality you need for calculating the asymptotic complexity is `k < n` (because each element can be misplaced by at most `n - 1` positions). Therefore:

`k + n * logk < n + n * logk = n * (1 + logk)`, which is `O(n * logk)`.

Comment: That makes sense, I see where my error in analysis is. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Mr.Mips Glad to help!